# Datetime picker selection getting auto update

Tags: ios, cordova, vue.js, quasar, qdatetime

On iOS platform after selection Datetime picker(q-datetime-picker), text-field getting update automatically.

**Date picker bug**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: This issue coming only on iOS, on android it working fine.

Comment: It actually converts to local times zone, by adding 5:30 in selected time. How I prevent this.

Comment: This can also be replicate on safari.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem, to correct on my app, i had to use skwas-cordova-plugin-datetimepicker

Installation :

```
cordova plugin add skwas-cordova-plugin-datetimepicker
```

Source :
https://github.com/skwasjer/skwas-cordova-plugin-datetimepicker

Comment: Is it quasar based mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

After updates `quasar upgrade -i` it working fine.